# Angular SystemJS require adds extension to .html file

Tags: typescript, angular, systemjs

I'm building a simple Angular Application using Typescript. I'm using gulp to build it.
I'm trying to save the html and css files for each component in seperate files.

Example:

```
components
    - app.component.ts
    - app.component.html
    - app.component.scss
```

I'm including the files like this

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: require('./app.component.html')
})
export class AppComponent { }
```

The Problem is, that it is trying to load the file *./app.component.html.js* as shown on the network-tools in chrome.
[Chrome Network-Tools Request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xyc5N.png)

If i open the requested url in my browser and remove the *.js* at the end, the file gets displayed correctly.

**systemjs.config.js**

```
(function(global) {
    // map tells the System loader where to look for things
    var map = {
        'app':                        '', // 'dist',
        '@angular':                   'libs/@angular',
        'angular2-in-memory-web-api': 'libs/angular2-in-memory-web-api',
        'rxjs':                       'libs/rxjs'
    };
    // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
    var packages = {
        'app':                        { main: 'main.js', defaultExtension: 'js' },
        'rxjs':                       { defaultExtension: 'js' },
        'angular2-in-memory-web-api': { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' }
    };
    var ngPackageNames = [
        'common',
        'compiler',
        'core',
        'forms',
        'http',
        'platform-browser',
        'platform-browser-dynamic',
        'router',
        'router-deprecated',
        'upgrade'
    ];
    // Individual files (~300 requests):
    function packIndex(pkgName) {
        packages['@angular/'+pkgName] = { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' };
    }
    // Bundled (~40 requests):
    function packUmd(pkgName) {
        packages['@angular/'+pkgName] = { main: '/bundles/' + pkgName + '.umd.js', defaultExtension: 'js' };
    }
    // Most environments should use UMD; some (Karma) need the individual index files
    var setPackageConfig = System.packageWithIndex ? packIndex : packUmd;
    // Add package entries for angular packages
    ngPackageNames.forEach(setPackageConfig);
    var config = {
        map: map,
        packages: packages
    };
    System.config(config);
})(this);
```

If I'm storing the html and css directly in the components, everything works as expected.

[**Project Structure**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kl7v1.png)

Comment: did you try `templateUrl: 'app.component.html'` instead of `template: require('./app.component.html')`?

Comment: its loading the file if i add the folder too:     
`templateUrl: 'components/app.component.html'`

is it somehow possible to do it without the folder?

Comment: So it works now? :)

Comment: same for css but here you should pass array of strings instead of single string: `styleUrls: ['app.component.scss']`. You can find a **Component configuration** cheatsheet [here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/cheatsheet.html). I'm not sure if sass will work in this case, you can try anyway.

Comment: Yeah, thank you. I got it working. I think a solution without the containing folder would be nicer but it works. Thank you. Please add an answer so i can accept it :)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback :) Added an answer along with the solution without the containing folder ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [cheatsheet](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/cheatsheet.html) **Component configuration** chapter you can pass external html and css as following:

`templateUrl: 'components/app.component.html',
 styleUrls: ['components/app.component.css']`

And you can make the path relative to component instead of relative to application root by adding `moduleId: module.id` to `@Component` directive.

`@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: 'app.component.html',
  styleUrls:  ['app.component.css']
})`

You can find the full description [here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/component-styles.html#!#relative-urls).

But you also have to manage how you convert your sass files into css before.